# php array val in put this array val

Tags: php, arrays

my idea is

```
<input type="text" name="pollName[] " id="pollName[]"/>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pollName[]" id="pollName[]" />
```

My array returns the following:

```
Array ( [0] => ask1 [1] => on [2] => ask2 [3] => ask3 [4] => on )
```

But I want output like below:

```
Array(ask1=>on, ask2=>, ask3=>on)
```

Comment: [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is the function you want

Comment: And what's the meaning of `ask2=> ask3=>on` ?

Comment: Please don't use spaces in either the name attribute or the id attribute

Comment: check box checked return 'on'. this is true answer

Comment: 2 elements should not have same id. The textbox and checkbox both have same id.

Comment: I build Poll. But many question in many true answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two different names : `pollName[]` `pollAnswer[]`

```
<input type="text" name="pollName[] " id="pollName[]"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="pollAnswer[]" id="pollAnswer[]" />
```

You could get the result you want by using something along these lines :

```
//  Test data :
//  $pollName = array('ask1','ask2','ask3');
//  $pollAnswer = array('On','','On');

    $pollResult = array();
    foreach( $pollName as $index => $name )
    {
        $pollResult[$name] = $pollAnswer[$index];
    }

    print_r( $pollResult );
```

Will output :

```
Array ( [ask1] => On [ask2] => [ask3] => On )
```